# update an attribute using core data

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I have an entity that has 3 attributes: firstname, lastname and score. i am able to search the score of a person by firstname and last name and display it on an UILabel (so far so good) my problem is that i don't know how to update the score attribute with a new value. below the code that i use to perform the search and display the old value.

```
NSEntityDescription *entitydesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Scorecard" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
[request setEntity:entitydesc];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstname like %@ and lastname like %@", self.firstnameTextField.text, self.lastnameTextField.text];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSError *error;
NSArray *integer = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

if(integer.count <= 0){
    self.displayLabel.text = @"No records found";

}

else {

    NSNumber *score;

    for (NSManagedObject *object in integer) {


       score = [object valueForKey:@"score"];

        int x = [score intValue];

       // New Value is going to be the old value + 2
        int y = x + 2;

      //displays old value found
        [self.displayLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"old value %d",x]];

    }

}
```

**update #1**

i was able to update the attribute and save it however i had to convert my new Integer value to a string and then convert it back to an integer. i don't like the extra step. if anyone has another suggestion please let me know and thanks for the help. below the updated code.

```
 NSEntityDescription *entitydesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Scorecard" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
[request setEntity:entitydesc];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstname like %@ and lastname like %@", self.firstnameTextField.text, self.lastnameTextField.text];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSError *error;
NSArray *integer = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

if(integer.count <= 0){
    self.displayLabel.text = @"No records found";

}

else {

    NSNumber *score;

    for (NSManagedObject *object in integer) {

        score = [object valueForKey:@"score"];

        int x = [score intValue];
        int y = x + 2;
        NSString* z = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",y];

        [object setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[z integerValue]] forKey:@"score"];
        [self.displayLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Value updated to %d",y]];
        [context save:&error];

    }

}
```

**update 2**

Thanks to Kevin's answer I was able to solve my problem. I am now able to replace an integer value from an attribute on my core data with another integer value. below my code finally working.

```
NSEntityDescription *entitydesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Scorecard" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
[request setEntity:entitydesc];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstname like %@ and lastname like %@", self.firstnameTextField.text, self.lastnameTextField.text];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSError *error;
NSArray *integer = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

if(integer.count <= 0){
self.displayLabel.text = @"No records found";

}

else {

NSNumber *score;

for (NSManagedObject *object in integer) {

    score = [object valueForKey:@"score"];

    int x = [score intValue];
    int y = x + 2;

    [object setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:y] forKey:@"score"];
    [self.displayLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Value updated to %d",y]];
    [context save:&error];

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get an object like you did before then set's it's score property

```
[object setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:y] forKey:@"score"];
```

Comment: [object setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[score integerValue]] forKey:@"score"]; i added this line of code since is an integer the number that i want to update but when i check the data the number is not updated any recommendations?

Comment: im not seeing any changes cause im assigning the old value again, my bad. any way i can assign the "int y" value? i think i am almost there but i am missing something.

Comment: Updated for int y, sorry

Comment: No problem, also something I should mention - if you create an .xcdatamodeld, then you can create your entities, set their attributes and relationships, and use Core Data generated classes to interact with your objects through properties. Ray Wenderlich has a great tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion would be to use NSManagedObject's subclasses instead of using primitives. You can do this by using the core data inspector and changing your entity class.

Now, to do a change to the score, you need to find the object you need to change, and assign the value. Once the value is assigned, you will need to save the NSManagedObject the object belongs to. Once the context successfully saves, your changes are persistent.